# system generated xls reports is bigger than modified report

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, xls

when I generate a report using asp.net with c# into xls format it is initially approximately 32 MB. But when i open it using excel and save it as xls format providing different name, the size is reduced to approximately 10 KB, but the data and the formatting  isnt lost both the file appear identical in Excel.

why is that so?

How could i initially generate a report of smaller file size?

**32MB File Size** contains data like

```
<tr height="20" style='height:15.00pt;'>
    <td class="xl66" height="20" style='height:15.00pt;' x:str>PR</td>
    <td class="xl72" x:str>00923</td>
    <td class="xl66" align="right" x:num>2016</td>
    <td class="xl66" align="right" x:num>25</td>
    <td class="xl66" align="right" x:num>89</td>
    <td class="xl66" align="right" x:num>89</td>
    <td class="xl66" align="right" x:num>45</td>
    <td class="xl66" align="right" x:num>52</td>
    <td class="xl66" align="right" x:num>2316</td>
    <td class="xl73" align="right" x:num="0.87">87%</td>
    <td class="xl73" align="right" x:num="1.e-002">1%</td>
    <td class="xl73" align="right" x:num="4.0000000000000001e-002">4%</td>
    <td class="xl73" align="right" x:num="4.0000000000000001e-002">4%</td>
    <td class="xl73" align="right" x:num="2.e-002">2%</td>
    <td class="xl73" align="right" x:num="2.e-002">2%</td>
    <td class="xl73" align="right" x:num="0.92000000000000004">92%</td>
</tr>
```

**10MB file** contains some random functions as in

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f979595cf169575aea3b94d9abc3b525

Comment: You appear to be generating HTML that Excel can understand, not a native Excel file.  Re-saving it produces a correctly formatted file (xml or binary) that will be significantly smaller (because the binary format is very efficient and the xml format is compressed)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am using following code to generate the excel sheet, can you give the suggestion to improve the codings   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/913e9ee9127b775bd1cd8ac52c59019a

Comment: Creating a proper Excel file is the best way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create xlsx files. It should has smaller size.
Or if you stuck with coding, you can try to use report generators, like a Crystal or FastReport.Net (it has an exports in xls and xlsx too).